# Select default value if no old input is set

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using form model binding and have the following select input :

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', $users, old('user_id') ?: Auth::id(), ['class' => 'form-control select2 users']) !!}
```

I would like to accomplish the following:

- In the creation form: select the option where the `user_id` equals the authenticated user's ID, **but** if there was old input in the session, select that option instead.
- In the edit form: always select the option that is stored in the model.

`old('user_id') ?: Auth::id()` doesn't seem to work when editing, because it always selects the option of the authenticated user and not the one that is stored in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have this line,

```
  {!! Form::Model($users, ['route' => ['admin.user.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
```

then your code should like this:

```
{!! Form::select('user_id', $users, isset($selectedUser) ? $selectedUser : null) !!}
```

at Create function do not pass $selectedUser to view but pass the id in your session,and in your edit function you should pass $selectedUser to view  ,which is Auth::user()->id

Comment: I had hoped there would a way to avoid defining the selected user in my controllers, because I need this in about 6 controllers. I hate duplicate code.

Comment: @EsTeGe, because it always have a session user_id i think, here is another id, you can try to judge your current route,if it is edit use give it a null value.  \@if (Route::currentRouteName() === 'admin.user.update') do a logic \@endif